# Receiving "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages." after trying to install python -setuptools and python-pip

Tags: apt, python

I ran "sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-pip" but I received:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 1.5.4-1ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

i normally only run sudo apt-get install python-pip and it works, i dont know why i decided to try setuptools. i tried going on Synaptic Package Manager, click on "Edit" in the menu bar, and click on "Fix broken packages" and the command line `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get -f install` but i am still unable to install python-pip.

i am on linux mint 17 xfce 3.13.0-37-generic, using Python 2.7.6.

any help is greatly appreciated. i saw alot of commands online regarding dpkg but im not familiar enough with packages and i do not want to break anything else.

**updates:**

"sudo apt-cache policy python-pip"

```
python-pip:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.4-1ubuntu3
  Version table:
     1.5.4-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     1.5.4-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

"sudo apt-get install python-pip-whl"

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-pip-whl : Depends: python-requests-whl but it is not installable
                  Depends: python-setuptools-whl but it is not installable
                  Depends: python-six-whl but it is not installable
                  Depends: python-urllib3-whl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**update #2**

$ sudo apt-cache policy python-pip-whl python-requests-whl python-setuptools-whl python-six-whl python-urllib3-whl

```
python-pip-whl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.4-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.5.4-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
python-requests-whl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
python-setuptools-whl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
python-six-whl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
python-urllib3-whl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.7.1-1ubuntu3
  Version table:
     1.7.1-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
```

$ for pkg in python-requests-whl python-setuptools-whl python-six-whl python-urllib3-whl; do sudo apt-get install $pkg; done

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-requests-whl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-requests-whl' has no installation candidate
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-setuptools-whl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-setuptools-whl' has no installation candidate
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-six-whl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-six-whl' has no installation candidate
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-urllib3-whl : Depends: python-six-whl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**update #3**

$ /etc/apt/sources.list

`#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17.1 _Rebecca_ - Release amd64 20150107]/ trusty contrib main non-free`

**update #4**

$ /etc/apt/sources.list.d $ ll

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 21 01:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jun 24 00:52 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   59 Jan  7 12:29 getdeb.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  530 Jan  7 12:29 official-package-repositories.list
```

$ cat getdeb.list

```
# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu trusty-getdeb apps
```

$ cat official-package-repositories.list

```
# Do not edit this file manually, use Software Sources instead.

deb http://packages.linuxmint.com rebecca main upstream import  #id:linuxmint_main
deb http://extra.linuxmint.com rebecca main #id:linuxmint_extra

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty partner
```

**update #5**

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d $ ll

```
total 52
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 24 01:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jun 24 00:52 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   49 Jun 21 00:59 00aptitude
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   41 Jan  7 11:58 00cdrom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   73 Jan  7 11:58 00recommends
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   40 Jun 21 00:58 00trustcdrom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  643 Apr 10  2014 01autoremove
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  992 Jan  7 12:23 01autoremove-kernels
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  123 Apr 10  2014 20changelog
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  243 Mar 11  2013 20dbus
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2331 Apr  2  2014 50unattended-upgrades
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  182 Feb 23  2014 70debconf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   33 Jun 24 01:06 99synaptic
```

/etc/apt/preferences.d $ ll

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 21 01:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jun 24 00:52 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  216 Feb  3 07:15 official-extra-repositories.pref
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  171 Jan  7 12:29 official-package-repositories.pref
```

Comment: The pip that is shipping with Linux Mint 17 is outdated, you should use the [documented instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) to install `pip`.

Comment: @StephenKitt Updated question sir. Are all of the errors above related to python-setuptools? This is my 3rd time setting up dual-boot for windows 8 and linux mint but before yesterday i never did setuptools. I was able to install pip. However pip would return ssl errors, i assume because it is an outdated version. Updating pip did not help either. Normally on windows i install pip via the method Anthon mentioned above through the get-pip.py script.

Comment: No, it seems your system can no longer find architecture-independent packages (with `all` instead of `amd64`)... Could you add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` to your question? You wouldn't happen to have `[arch=...]` qualifiers in there by any chance?

Comment: @StephenKitt i found this link: `http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/482` is that solution feasible? i do not need to install python setup tools using `apt-get install python-setuptools`, if it is easier, can i "clear" the system from trying to resolve the broken packages? (are the broken packages python-setuptools dependencies?)

Comment: @jes516 That article is out of date, it's safe now to use `aptitude` and `apt-get` interchangeably. There's something else wrong, your system should be able to find the packages in http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/six/ for example and install them. What do `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and `/etc/apt/preferences` contain on your system?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; you can fix it by updating first:

```
# apt-get update
```